# Why is as.data.frame ignoring col.names = vector

Tags: r, dataframe

I'm stubbornly trying to create a data frame in one line with named rows and columns.  I realize I can do this easily by using colnames(forecast) but wanted to simplify, if only to prove I could do it.

The following does not work--no error, but column names are not set

```
forecast <- as.data.frame(cbind(c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152,
                                182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                                c(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181,
                                212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365),
                                as.vector(rep(0, times=12))),
                                row.names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                                               "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                                col.names = c("Start", "End", "forecast"))


> forecast
     V1  V2 V3
Jan   1  31  0
Feb  32  59  0
Mar  60  90  0
Apr  91 120  0
May 121 151  0
Jun 152 181  0
Jul 182 212  0
Aug 213 243  0
Sep 244 273  0
Oct 274 304  0
Nov 305 334  0
Dec 335 365  0
```

The following does work as desired.

```
forecast <- setNames(data.frame(cbind(c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152,
                                      182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                                      c(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181,
                                      212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365),
                                      as.vector(rep(0, times=12))),
                                      row.names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                                                "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec")),
                                      c("Start", "End", "forecast"))

> forecast
    Start End forecast
Jan     1  31        0
Feb    32  59        0
Mar    60  90        0
Apr    91 120        0
May   121 151        0
Jun   152 181        0
Jul   182 212        0
Aug   213 243        0
Sep   244 273        0
Oct   274 304        0
Nov   305 334        0
Dec   335 365        0
```

It just seems odd to have to nest in another function.  In the as.data.frame docs it says to use col.names = names(x).  Does that mean it can only generate names from the input object?

Comment: What language is this? ("DataFrames" is a concept that exists in many languages, e.g. R, Julia and Python. This looks like R to me, but I've never actually worked with R, so I am really just guessing...)

Comment: Sorry.  This is in R.

Comment: Why not just: `data.frame(Start = c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152,
                      182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                    End= c(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181,
                      212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365),
                    forecast = as.vector(rep(0, times=12)),
              row.names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                            "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"))` ?

Comment: @tushaR--thanks, that worked.

Answer (score 1):

The data's class is matrix:

```
d <- cbind(c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152,
                            182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                            c(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181,
                            212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365),
                            as.vector(rep(0, times=12)))
is.matrix(d)
# TRUE
```

If you check the method `as.data.frame` uses, it is as followed:

```
## S3 method for class 'character'
as.data.frame(x, ...,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

## S3 method for class 'list'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE, ...,
              cut.names = FALSE, col.names = names(x), fix.empty.names = TRUE,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())

## S3 method for class 'matrix'
as.data.frame(x, row.names = NULL, optional = FALSE,
              make.names = TRUE, ...,
              stringsAsFactors = default.stringsAsFactors())
```

You can see that option `col.names` can only be used in named list object. You can simply change from `cbind()` to `list()` to make it work:

```
forecast <- as.data.frame(list(c(1, 32, 60, 91, 121, 152,
                                182, 213, 244, 274, 305, 335),
                                c(31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181,
                                212, 243, 273, 304, 334, 365),
                                as.vector(rep(0, times=12))),
                                row.names = c("Jan", "Feb", "Mar", "Apr", "May", "Jun", 
                                               "Jul", "Aug", "Sep", "Oct", "Nov", "Dec"),
                                col.names = c("Start", "End", "forecast"))

#     Start End forecast
# Jan     1  31        0
# Feb    32  59        0
# Mar    60  90        0
# Apr    91 120        0
# May   121 151        0
# Jun   152 181        0
# Jul   182 212        0
# Aug   213 243        0
# Sep   244 273        0
# Oct   274 304        0
# Nov   305 334        0
# Dec   335 365        0
```